# Multiple items from json

Tags: python, scrapy

I got json from api and there's one field that looks like:

```json
{"list_of_something":[
       {"first_name": "name",
        "property_one": "property",
        "property_two": "property"
       },
       {"first_name": "name",
        "property_one": "property",
        "property_two": "property"
       },
 ....
```

I want to put it in one item. I tried this

```py
        if json_data.get('list_of_something'):
        for item in json_data['list_of_something']:
            resource = {"first_name": item.get('first_name'),
                            "property_one": item.get('property_one'),
                           }
```

but it only collects the last entry.
I want to collect it like one item "resource", that contains every thing from "list_of_something".
How can i do this?
UPD.
I need only a few fields ,not every field from list_of_something

Comment: Obviously only one thing can be assigned to a dictionary property like "property_one".  Is your goal to make the keys unique or to convert "property_one" to an array that contains all of the values from the items in "list_of_something"?

Comment: Please provide example input and expected output.

Comment: i want to make "resource" that contains list of dicts

Comment: output : 
'resource': [{'name': 'name1',
                   'property_one': '123123123',
                   'property_two': '74955877788'},
{'name': 'name2',
                   'property_one': '333333333',
                   'property_two': '44444444'},
]

Comment: The list_of_something is already a list of dict and if generating "resource" which is also a list of dict identical to list_of_something is the requirement then why to use these for loops. You can just assign the list_of_something to "resource".

Comment: yes! i forgot to say, that i need special fields from list_of_something, not every

Answer (score 0):

```
if json_data.get('list_of_something'):
    resource = []
    for item in json_data['list_of_something']:
        resource.append({"first_name": item.get('first_name'),
                        "property_one": item.get('property_one'),
                        "property_two": item.get('property_two')})
```

Is a `resource` list in that format what you're looking for ?

You could simply do this:

`resource = json_data['list_of_something']`

Comment: @SorryCigane Isn't list_of_something already a list of dicts?

Comment: @saquintes It is in the example input, so there should be no reason to iterate through its items, if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: @saquintes yes!
i forgot to say, that i need special firleds from list_of_something, not every

Comment: You can do this in one line using list comprehension.

Comment: @SorryCigane `[{"first_name": item.get('first_name'), "property_one: item.get('property_one'), "property_two": item.get('property_two')} for item in json_data['list_of_something']]`

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are after is already a list of the items in the result of your json.loads() operation. Your message could imply that you may want to rename the keys. You made the first key "second_name" in the second entry after the first one being "first_name". Anyway, you can do something like:

```
resource = json_data.get('list_of_something')
if resource:
    <rename the keys in a for loop if that is what you wanted>
    <do the thing to the stuff to achieve the outcome>
else:
    <handle 'list_of_something' not being in the json>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement I can see that you want particular keys from the `dict` element in the `json_data list` to be present inside the dict element for the `resource` list.

Consider keeping the required keys in a list and then iterating over it.
Refer to the snippet below

```
json_data = {"list_of_something":[
       {"first_name": "name",
        "property_one": "property",
        "property_two": "property"
       },
       {"first_name": "name",
        "property_one": "property",
        "property_two": "property"
       }
    ]
}

resource = []
list_of_keys_required = ["first_name", "property_one"]
if json_data.get('list_of_something'):
    for item in json_data['list_of_something']:
        new_dict = {}
        for key,value in item.items():
            if key in list_of_keys_required:
                new_dict[key] = value
        resource.append(new_dict)


print(resource)
```

The above will give you the output as

```
[{'first_name': 'name', 'property_one': 'property'}, {'first_name': 'name', 'property_one': 'property'}]
```

Comment: You should change `list_of_keys_required` to be a set.

Comment: Why do we have to do that?

Comment: we don't *have* to do that, but sets are faster then lists. and there's no reason why not to use them (in this case).